# Binary requests in Unix domain sockets

Tags: sockets, binary

I want to have a local server in Unix to handle concurrent requests, if it's possible, and whose response would be in binary format.

Are the Unix domain sockets right for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, if you only need to accept connections from local processes (i.e. not over a network).